# Saving MySQL records as a series of Insert Statements

Tags: mysql

Having carefully and painfully manually populated/manipulated a series of records in a table, I want to retain them for reuse. As the table is rewritten daily I'd like to save JUST these particular records as a series of "inserts". The only way I know how to do this is to dump the whole table as sql using a GUI eg sqlyog.

But is there any quicker/better way to do this?

Comment: In fact sqlyog will allow me to save a selected set of records as sql. But I've still learnt from the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you still have your clean manually populated table available. Copy it into another table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_backup SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Then you can re-introduce these to your daily rebuild table using a similar method:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable_backup;
```

Does this help?

Comment: Greg, looks good I guess you can add a where to 

CREATE TABLE mytable_backup SELECT * FROM mytable where blah-blah;

Answer (score 1):

would [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) help ? (it's not a GUI)

edit : note that you can save only part of a table using this tool. since it's command line, you can automate the task easily.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of your table with a meaningful name and copy using a INSERT the records your interested in.

Doing it this way gives the most flexibility should you need to copy them back/compare them.